# using mysql calculate balance of each currency where credit and debit in same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following MySQL table containing debit or credit "actions" with associated amounts and currency, how is it possible to select all `CLIENT_IDs` with a non-zero `"balance"` of each `currency`? I have tried but something isn't working correctly.

```
CLIENT_ID    ACTION_TYPE    ACTION_AMOUNT    Currency
1            debit          1000                USD
1            credit         100                 USD
1            credit         500                 DR
2            debit          1000                EURO
2            credit         1200                DR
3            debit          1000                EURO
3            credit         1000                USD
4            debit          1000                USD
```

My MySQL query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT client_id,
       SUM(if(action_type='credit',action_amount,0)) as credit,
       SUM(if(action_type='debit',action_amount,0 )) as debit,
       SUM(if(currency='USD' ,action_type='credit'- action_type='debit' )) as USD_balance,
       SUM(if(currency='EURO',action_type='credit'- action_type='debit' )) as EURO_balance,
       SUM(if(currency='DR'  ,action_type='credit'- action_type='debit' )) as DR_balance
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY client_id,currency
```

The result I am expecting is something like:

```
CLIENT_ID    USD_Balance    EURO_Balance    DR_Balance
1              -900             0              500
2                0            -1000            1200
3              1000           -1000             0
4             -1000              0              0
```

I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Group By client_id` including `Conditional Aggregation` as below

```
SELECT client_id,
       SUM(case when action_type = 'credit' then action_amount else 0 end) as credit,
       SUM(case when action_type = 'debit'  then action_amount else 0 end) as debit,
       SUM(case
             when currency = 'USD' and action_type = 'credit' then
              action_amount else 0
           end) - SUM(case
                        when currency = 'USD' and action_type = 'debit' then
                         action_amount
                        else 0
                      end) as USD_balance,
       SUM(case
             when currency = 'EURO' and action_type = 'credit' then
              action_amount else 0
           end) - SUM(case
                        when currency = 'EURO' and action_type = 'debit' then
                         action_amount
                        else 0
                      end) as EUR_balance,
       SUM(case
             when currency = 'DR' and action_type = 'credit' then
              action_amount
             else 0
           end) - SUM(case
                        when currency = 'DR' and action_type = 'debit' then
                         action_amount
                        else 0
                      end) as DR_balance
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY client_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a2972c3dc456e3e7b1c94fb9eb8fd19e)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_id   
     , currency
     , SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'debit' THEN action_amount * -1 ELSE action_amount END) balance 
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY client_id
     , currency
```

The rest of the problem can (and should) be resolved in application code

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY` on `client_id` only, as you are trying to "pivot" on multiple currencies in different columns. You will need to use two levels of `If()` statements to compute balance.

Try the following:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
       SUM(IF(Currency = 'USD', IF(ACTION_TYPE = 'credit', ACTION_AMOUNT, -ACTION_AMOUNT), 0)) AS USD_Balance, 
       SUM(IF(Currency = 'EURO', IF(ACTION_TYPE = 'credit', ACTION_AMOUNT, -ACTION_AMOUNT), 0)) AS EURO_Balance, 
       SUM(IF(Currency = 'DR', IF(ACTION_TYPE = 'credit', ACTION_AMOUNT, -ACTION_AMOUNT), 0)) AS DR_Balance
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.but this query show when all balance is zero, i dont want like this result.